# Where are the Optimal Tours of TSPLIB 95 Instances?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, reference-works

I am looking for the optimal tours of the TSPLIB 95 instances as downloadable files. I have checked several places, but all lists I could find contain gaps, despite the fact, that all instances have been solved to optimality.

**Question:**
which publicly accessible repositiories contain (links to) a downloadable optimal tour for each of the benchmark instances of the TSPLIB 95, at least for the Symmetric Traveling Salesman problems?

Comment: Now posted also on MathOverflow: [Publicly Accessible TSPLib95 Solutions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/292361)

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to find the optimal tours. This link has some of them:
https://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/tsp/

For other instances, the best I found is their optimal length:
https://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/STSP.html